# Pushing arrays; storing more than one value into a single key

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to store multiple values (titles) into a single key. I prompt the user the input their title first, and then save it to 'titles'. But when I enter multiple values, only one value is attached to the key 'titles'. Also, it says titles.push isn't a function.

```
//get the title from user
var title = prompt("What would you like your title to be?");
localStorage.setItem(title, editElem.innerHTML); 

//save the editor contents to local storage based on title
document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = "Edits saved!";
var theDiv = document.getElementById("Contentable");
var content = document.createTextNode(title);
theDiv.appendChild(content);
var br = document.createElement("br");
theDiv.appendChild(br);

//save the all titles in array so you know what documents exist
var titles = localStorage.getItem("titles");
if(titles == null) 
    titles = new Array();
if(titles.indexOf(title) < 0) 
    titles.push(title); 
localStorage.setItem("titles", titles);
```

Comment: `if(titles.indexOf(title) < 0)` will always be true for a `new Array()`

Comment: Never omit braces, especially with bad indentation. It makes your code unreadable

Comment: `titles` must be an array for `title.push` to be a function. I don't think that's what being returned by the `localStorage.getItem`, which usually is a string. -- **You must use `JSON.stringify` if you wish to save JS objects (such as HTML) in localStorage.**

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) can only store **strings**, not arrays. When you pass an array to `setItem` it call Array's `toString()` method to cast an array to a string. Then, when you call `getItem`, it return string representation which won't be casted to array autom'ly, unless you do it manually. And I guess you don't so.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following object to push titles to the storage. Note how `JSON.stringify` converts from `Array` to `string`, and how `JSON.parse` does the opposite.

```
var titlesStore =
        {
            Count: function () {
                var stack = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("titles"));
                if (!stack)
                    return 0;
                return stack.length;
            },
            Peek: function () {
                var stack = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("title"));
                if (!stack)
                    stack = [];
                if (stack.length > 0)
                    return stack.pop();
            },
            Push: function (token) {
                var stack = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("titles"));
                if (!stack)
                    stack = [];
                stack.push(token);
                localStorage.setItem("title", JSON.stringify(stack));
            },
            // more methods to you might wish to implement: search, insert, etc.
        }

    // usage:
    titlesStore.Push("new title"); // sets the last title
    titlesStore.Peek(); // gets the last title ;
```